# Send and receive commands from Android device to PLC

Tags: android, command, wifi, wifi-direct, plc

I am trying to command a pre-programmed PLC using an Android device. I need to be able to, for example, update boolean values or receive an integer value from the PLC. The PLC is connected to a router which creates its own wireless network which I can connect the phone. How would I go about doing this/can anyone link documentation on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all which PLC are you using?

If you are using siemens you can use these [Sharp 7(C#) or Moka 7 (java)](http://snap7.sourceforge.net/) to achieve communication over S7 siemens protocol.